# How to update Access database using a datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview

I have a `datagridview` that bind with a `datatable` and using `DataPropertyName` the `datagridview` only shows 4 columns of `database`.
this is how I bind `database` to a `datagridview`:

```
string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
OleDbDataAdapter DataA = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from SelectedFeeds", Connection);
DataTable DTable = new DataTable();
DataA.Fill(DTable);

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].Name = "نام خوراک";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].HeaderText = "نام خوراک";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[1].DataPropertyName = "Feed Name / Description";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].Name = "مقدار (کیلوگرم)";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].HeaderText = "مقدار (کیلوگرم)";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[2].DataPropertyName = "Quantity";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].Name = "درصد (خوراک)";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].HeaderText = "درصد (خوراک)";
frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.Columns[3].DataPropertyName = "Percent";

frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.DataSource = DTable;
```

So far nothing wrong,

now I want when user change the value of `Columns[2]`, it's value automatically inserted (and after that updated) into `database` I tryed myself using this code but seems that it's wrong, the code is:

```
string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
Cmd.Connection = Connection;
double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.CurrentCell.Value);
string FeedName = frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
Connection.Open();
Cmd.CommandText="Update SelectedFeeds set Quantity=" +Quantity  'Where Feed Name / Description'= FeedName;
Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
Connection.Close();
```

the first problem is that my CommandText is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.
what should I do?

Comment: Always use parameters.  If a field name has a space or is a keyword, you have to put brackets around it, so `[Feed Name / Description]`.  BTW, that's a horrible column name.

Comment: As larstexh said you should use paramatera as your quotatuons are wrong

Comment: @LarsTech tnx, can you explain it to me how I use parameters?

Comment: See [Adding Parameters ...](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23689242/719186)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tanks to @LarsTech the answer is:

```
public static void UpdateRationFeeds(Form1 frm)
{
    string StrCon = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FeedLibraryConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(StrCon);
    OleDbCommand Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    Cmd.Connection = Connection;
    double Quantity = Convert.ToDouble(frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.CurrentCell.Value);
    string FeedName = frm.RationFeedsdataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    Connection.Open();
    Cmd.CommandText = "Update SelectedFeeds set Quantity=@quantity Where SelectedFeeds.[Feed Name]=@feedname";
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", OleDbType.Double).Value = Quantity;
    Cmd.Parameters.Add("@feedname", OleDbType.LongVarChar).Value = FeedName;
    Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: `set Quantity = @quantity where...` then `Cmd.Parameters.Add("@quantity", ...`