# How to resolve the syntax error in UPDATE statement

Tags: vb.net

What is wrong with this code? I did everything but I still get a
syntax error in UPDATE statement

```
Dim konfirmasi As String = MsgBox("Yakin data ingin diubah ?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Konfirmasi")
If konfirmasi = vbYes Then
SqlQuery = "Update Tabel_Pengguna set " & _
            "Username = '" & txtUsername.Text & "'," & _
             "Password ='" & txtPassword.Text & "' where Kode_Pengguna = '" & txtKodePengguna.Text & "'"
CMD = New OleDbCommand(SqlQuery, DB)
CMD.ExecuteNonQuery()
MsgBox("Data berhasil diubah", vbInformation, "Informasi")
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned what Database you are using. I am going to guess Access and the word `Password` is a keyword, it needs to be wrapped in sqaure brackets `[  ]`.

Comment: Also, it is entirely possible the values in `txtUsername` and `txtPassword` are causing a parsing problem. Make use of Parameters to prevent this is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689213/adding-parameters-to-oledbconnection

Comment: Further to @JayV's comment - this looks like a SQL injection vulnerability. At the very least, apostrophes will break this statement (try adding a name of `O'Reilly`).

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

To make `MsgBox` work you would need to use the bitwise `Or` operator. This function returns a `MsgBoxResult` not a `String`. I suggest you change to the .net `MessageBo`x and leave the old VB6 code behind.

```
Private Sub OPCode()
    'Dim konfirmasi As MsgBoxResult = MsgBox("Yakin data ingin diubah ?", vbQuestion Or vbYesNo, "Konfirmasi")
    Dim konfirmasi As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Yakin data ingin diubah ?", "Konfirmasi", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question)
    If konfirmasi = DialogResult.Yes Then
        UpdatePengguna(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtKodePengguna.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Keep connection local to the method where they are used so they can be closed and disposed with `Using...End Using` blocks. In this code both the connection and the command are included in the `Using` block; note the comma at the end of the first line of the `Using`.

**Always** use parameters to avoid Sql injection. With OleDb the names of the parameters are ignored but we use descriptive names to make reading the code easier. It is the order that matters. The order that the parameters appear in the Sql statement must match the order which the parameters are added to the parameters collection. You will have to check your database for the correct datatypes and field sizes. I suspect `Kode_Pengguna` might be a numeric type. If so, be sure the change the datatype of the passed in parameter `PenKode`.

I believe you are neglecting to open your connection unless your are passing around open connections (be still my heart!). `Open` the connection at the last minute, directly before the `.Execute...` and close it as soon as possible with the `End Using`.

```
Private Sub UpdatePengguna(UserName As String, Password As String, PenKode As String)
    Using cn As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Update Tabel_Pengguna Set [UserName] = @Username, [Password] = @Password Where Kode_Pengguna = @Kode;", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = UserName
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = Password
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Kode", OleDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = PenKode
        cn.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
    MessageBox.Show("Data berhasil diubah", "Informasi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
End Sub
```

I really hope you are not saving passwords as plain text.