# How do I fetch data from Access database records and display/save them as textboxes/variables in VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

coding noob here. I'm looking for help after hours of googling and watching YouTube tutorials provided no success. I've also tried looking at many of the posts on this website. I keep running into the same problem.

In Visual Studio I am attempting to create a solution with VB.net, it is currently successfully linked to an Access Database with which I can view, add, edit, and save records live.

I am trying to fetch data from the Access database based on a search of one of the fields, and then save that data as a variable.

(Code shown below)
Upon attempting to click the search button, I received the following exception: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'First Name'.'

I believe it is because my field names are two words, but I have no idea how to fix this. Just typing it with one word gives this exception instead:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

I have been completely unable to make progress despite watching multiple different versions of tutorials on how to perform this. Could someone please help me out?

Here is the code:

```
Public Class FormTraits

    Private Sub FormTraits_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    End Sub

    Private Sub FNButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FNButton.Click

        Dim conn As New OleDbConnection
        conn.ConnectionString = ("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Access Database.accdb")
        conn.Open()

        Dim strsql As String
        strsql = "select ID, First Name, Last Name from PlayerData where First Name=" + TextBoxSearch.Text + ""

        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(strsql, conn)

        Dim myreader As OleDbDataReader

        myreader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        myreader.Read()

        TextBoxFirstName.Text = myreader("First Name")
        TextBoxLastName.Text = myreader("Last Name")
        TextBoxID.Text = myreader("ID")

        conn.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Use [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters). Do **not** add the parameter with `"... Name="+ TextBoxSearch.Text`! And, btw, the `+ ""` at the end does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using names including spaces or other special characters for tables, columns, etc, in your database. Just as you would do for a variable name or the like in VB - and as you have done for your table name - you should name your columns `FirstName` and `LastName`. If you must include spaces or other special characters, you must escape the identifiers in your SQL code. You also need to wrap text literals in single quotes, much as you wrap them in double quotes in VB:

```vb
strsql = "SELECT ID, [First Name], [Last Name] FROM PlayerData WHERE [First Name] = '" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "'"
```

It would be better if you used parameters instead of string concatenation, but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: Hey! I appreciate the incredibly fast response. 

Yeah, I really should have made these field names one word like I made everything else. The square brackets was what I was looking for, as I didn't know how to specify that both words are one thing. Also, forgive me, but I do not understand what your very last sentence means, could you clarify? What are text literals?

Anyway, with your recommended changes, there is no more syntax error exception, but the latter exception now applies.

Comment: @today, did you include the single quotes where I specified?

Comment: I think so. This is that line of code now, is this what you meant?

strsql = "select ID, [First Name], [Last Name] from PlayerData where [First Name]= '" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "'"

Comment: His very last sentence means: [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters). And also this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689242/880990

Comment: Oh okay, well... I have no clue how to use that.

Comment: @today, there's plenty of places that you can get a clue, e.g. [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: @user18387401 I had a read through that website. While I understand the baseline reasons for using parameters, I don't get how to code it.

Comment: @today, given that that blog post demonstrates how to code it, I'm not sure what more you expect. As I already said though, that is beyond the scope of this question. If you have a question about ADO.NET parameters, post that as its own question, with all and only the information relevant to that question. You'd really need to show some sort of effort though, given that you've already been provided with various information and examples and there is plenty more out there too.